# PHP spreadsheet dropdownlist

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I want to know if it's possible to mapping a dropdownlist in phpspreadsheet, show in dropdownlist value form range cell, but when user choose show the value from second column .
Like :
I choose ine dropdownlist : AAA, when i choose : the worksheet show 111.
Because i have A1 = AAA and B1 = 111

Thxs for your help.

Comment: have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, sorry if i'm not enought clear .

I generaet two worksheet with phpspreadsheet. The first one, it's a simple sheet, the second it's a list with two column (ID -NAME) . I try to make a ddropdownlist in the first sheet , where I choose NAME of the second sheet, and when the choice it's ok, the sheet show the ID . 
Second sheet it's ok, I generate the list with my database. It's ok too for the dropdown list, 
I try a VLOOKUP , but's notworking

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 3;
foreach($providersList as $provider) {
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$i, $provider['id']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$i, $provider['Name']);
    $i++;
}
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$nbOfProvider = $sheet->getHighestRow('A');
for($j = 3; $j < $nbOfProvider; $j++) {
    $dropdownlist = $worksheet->getCell('B'.$j)->getDataValidation();
    $dropdownlist->setType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation::TYPE_LIST)    
                 ->setAllowBlank(true)
                 ->setShowDropDown(true)
                 ->setPrompt('Choose the provider')
                 ->setFormula1('=\'PROVIDERS\'!$B$3:$B$'.$nbOfProvider);
    $idProvider = $worksheet->getCell('C'. $j);
    /*$idProvider->setValue('=VLOOKUP(\'PROVIDERS\'!$B$3:$B$'.$nbOfProvider.',B');*/
}
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0);
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save($file);
return $file;
```